# How to disable automaticSize for specific item cell in a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

```
 override func viewDidLoad(){
       let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
       collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        }

}
```

above code working well as my expect.

but I need for 1st item  full width but it's not working anymore and give me exception.

```
extension  WordViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.item == 0{
        return  CGSize(width: self.collectionView.frame.width, height: 100)

    }
    return  UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
}
```

Exception :

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: -setFrame: with CGRectNull is
>   undefined.

Would you tell me how can i make 1st item full width other item keep `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`

Update:

if comment out flowing lines :

```
   // if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    //    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    // }
```

then make it this way then working fine.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.item == 0{
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 100)

    }
   return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
   }
```

Comment: Have you inherit UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ??

Comment: try this return CGSize(width: self.collectioView.frame.width, height: 100)

Comment: i inherit  `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` that's why it's working fine if remove this code `return  UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`

Comment: Can you show your full code? its hard until you show your full code.. Thanks

Comment: i notice exception throwing  this line ` return  UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`

Comment: please Edit your Question with your Code... Thanks

Comment: Have you set collectioView.delegate = self in ViewDidLoad method?

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz i edit and I added that `collectioView.delegate = self`

Comment: If you simply set return  UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize in SIZEForItem then its works fine?

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz no! not working

Comment: Thats mean you need to call DELEGATE.. Then definitely it works...

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz check my updated section

Comment: Uncoomment your above code and then

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.item == 0{
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 100)

    }
   }

Comment: and then use above code... Hope so it will work...

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz it's should not work

Comment: Comment again your code and use this func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { if indexPath.item == 0{ return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width - 20, height: 100) } }

Comment: error : `Missing return in a function expected to return 'CGSize'`